# Finding AVG ride time of members VS non-members

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data set for bike riders and there are times for members and non-members (casual). I have written two SQL queries and have the AVG ride times for them, but how would I combine the two queries so that it is in one table?

```
SELECT
   AVG(end_time-start_time) AS avg_member_ride_time
FROM
   `table`
WHERE
   member_type = "member"
;
SELECT
   AVG(end_time-start_time) AS avg_casual_ride_time
FROM
   `table`
WHERE
   member_type = "casual
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
member_type,
AVG(end_time-start_time) AS avg_member_ride_time 
FROM table 
GROUP BY member_type
```

Comment: You're welcome!Don't hesitate to mark the answer as answered if you can! Thank you :)

Comment: I tried to, it said that I needed at least 15 reputation to do so, but the vote has been recorded!